# how to get first element value in a div in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I know its basic question but i am new with python so i can't figure out how to get first element value using python

Here Is Html Code from which i just want to grab the value of fist span which is website in main-div:

```html
<div class= "main-div">
  <span><a class= "web-link" href="https://www.website.com"><span>website</a></span>
  <span><a class= "web-link" href="https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a></span>
  <span><a class= "web-link" href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></span>
</div>
```

I am using this python script but it print all three spans in from main-div

```html
website = jsoup.find_all("div", {"class": "main-div"})
for element in website:
  link = jsoup.find_all("a", {"class": "web-link"})
  for tag in link:
    websitelink = tag.get("href")
    print(websitelink)
```

Please help me to get my desire result. I want to print just website and skip rest. how could it possible

Comment: `soup.find("a", text="website")["href"]` then the order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
website = jsoup.find("div", {"class": "main-div"})  #find div
if website:
    link = website.find("a", href=True)   #find first link with href
    if link:
       print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you have written an extra `<span>` 
corrected code:

```
<div class= "main-div">
  <span><a class= "web-link" href="https://www.website.com">website</a></span>
  <span><a class= "web-link" href="https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a></span>
  <span><a class= "web-link" href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></span>
</div>
```

here `tag.get("href")` return a list and it is stored in `websitelink`.
you just have to write `websitelink[0]` to grab first element in list

```
website = jsoup.find_all("div", {"class": "main-div"})
for element in website:
  link = jsoup.find_all("a", {"class": "web-link"})
  for tag in link:
    websitelink = tag.get("href")
    print(websitelink[0])
```

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as the OP's  bar `websitelink[0]` would get the first letter of the string i.e `"h"`.